# Converting time from AM/PM format to military time in Python

Tags: python

Without using any libraries, I'm trying to solve the Hackerrank problem "[Time Conversion](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)", the problem statement of which is copied below.

[image]

I came up with the following:

```
time = raw_input().strip()

meridian = time[-2:]        # "AM" or "PM"
time_without_meridian = time[:-2]
hour = int(time[:2])

if meridian == "AM":
    hour = (hour+1) % 12 - 1
    print ("%02d" % hour) + time_without_meridian[2:]
elif meridian == "PM":
    hour += 12
    print str(hour) + time_without_meridian[2:]
```

However, this fails on one test case:

[image]

Since the test cases are hidden to the user, however, I'm struggling to see where the problem is occurring. "12:00:00AM" is correctly converted to "00:00:00", and "01:00:00AM" to "01:00:00" (with the padded zero). What could be wrong with this implementation?

Comment: This is a good question, please type out the text-as-image longhand. Also I have a similar related question about the general use of [Can't call a function on capture-group in the repl expression of re.sub? e.g. int(r'\1')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128923/cant-call-a-function-on-capture-group-in-the-repl-expression-of-re-sub-e-g-in?noredirect=1)

Comment: As your code correctly implements, '12' is a special case: '12PM' does not get converted to 12+12=24, whereas '12AM' does get converted to '00'. But it's simpler to handle the special-case for `hour==12` as @selbie does, rather than the contortion `hour = (hour+1) % 12 - 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's even simpler than how you have it.

```
hour = int(time[:2])
meridian = time[8:]
# Special-case '12AM' -> 0, '12PM' -> 12 (not 24)
if (hour == 12):
    hour = 0
if (meridian == 'PM'):
    hour += 12
print("%02d" % hour + time[2:8])
```

Comment: It helps if you explain '12' is a special case: '12PM' does not get converted to 12+12=24, whereas '12AM' does get converted to '00'

Answer (score 9):

You've already solved the problem but here's another possible answer:

```
from datetime import datetime


def solution(time):
    return datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M:%S%p').strftime('%H:%M:%S')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        "12:00:00PM",
        "12:00:00AM",
        "07:05:45PM"
    ]
    for t in tests:
        print solution(t)
```

Although it'd be using a python library :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime

#Note the leading zero in 05 below, which is required for the formats used below

regular_time = input("Enter a regular time in 05:48 PM format: ")

#%I is for regular time. %H is for 24 hr time, aka "military time"
#%p is for AM/PM

military_time = datetime.strptime(regtime, '%I:%M %p').strftime('%H:%M')

print(f"regular time is: {regular_time"}
print(f"militarytime is {military_time}")
```

The following link proved to be very helpful:  https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: it was converting "12:00:00PM" to "24:00:00" and not "12:00:00". I modified the code as follows:

```
time = raw_input().strip()

meridian = time[-2:]        # "AM" or "PM"
time_without_meridian = time[:-2]
hour = int(time[:2])

if meridian == "AM":
    hour = (hour+1) % 12 - 1
    print ("%02d" % hour) + time_without_meridian[2:]
elif meridian == "PM":
    hour = hour % 12 + 12
    print str(hour) + time_without_meridian[2:]
```

leading to it passing all the test cases (see below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
dt_m = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time)
hour_m = (dt_m.hour%12)+1  #dt_m.hour+1
offset_dt = datetime.datetime(dt_m.year, dt_m.month, dt_m.day, hour_m , dt_m.minute, dt_m.second, dt_m.microsecond)
```